# kotlin class, I modify a list outside a class and it ends up modifying the value inside the class

Tags: android, list, class, kotlin, constructor

im trying to create a class with a list value. after create the object i clean the list outside the class but the list inside the class clear too

here is the code any suggestion ?

```
data class Profile(
    val links: List<Link>,
    val usersName : String,
    var profilePK : Int
)
```

```
profiles.add(
             Profile(
                 links,
                 cursor.getString(1),
                 auxProfilePK
                 )
             )
Log.i("BLE","Profile ID: "+profiles.last().profilePK.toString()+" LINK SIZE "+ profiles.last().links.size.toString())

links.clear()

Log.i("BLE","Profile ID: "+profiles.last().profilePK.toString()+" LINK SIZE "+ profiles.last().links.size.toString())
```

logs output:
Profile ID: 1 LINK SIZE 1
Profile ID: 1 LINK SIZE 0

Comment: You need to create a copy of the list using `list.toList()` or `List(list)`. Better yet, don't use MutableLists in the first place if you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that despite you expect an immutable list, the data class also accepts mutable lists - and as you only copy reference in Kotlin and Java, you can still work with the values outside the data class.

In order to making the profile class the sole owner of the list it gets passed, you need to copy it - either outside or inside the data class. I would suggest that you do this within the profile class to encapsulate this logic properly. The copying approach can be done in an init block or a secondary constructor then. There's a catch on data classes though that only parameters on the primary constructor are part of the default `equals`/`toHash` .

So here's a suggestion on how the profile class can look like, making the primary constructor private and having a secondary one which manages the conversion (there might be nicer options, but it's a start):

```kotlin
data class Profile private constructor(val links: List<Link>,
                                       val usersName : String,
                                       var profilePK : Int) {
    constructor(usersName: String, profilePK: Int, outerLinks: List<Link>) : 
        this(outerLinks.toList(), usersName, profilePK)
}
```